# Memory Error Python while processing large database

Tags: python, memory, pycharm

When I run this on Pycharm 4 on windows I got an error in this code:

```
PDBSumWWW = urllib.urlopen("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/pdbsum/data/seqdata.dat")
PDBSum = PDBSumWWW.read().splitlines()
PDBSumWWW.close()
```

This is the error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/LuisAlberto/PycharmProjects/MSc/SeqPDBSumIRIndex.py", line 98, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:/Users/LuisAlberto/PycharmProjects/MSc/SeqPDBSumIRIndex.py", line 40, in main
>       PDBSum = PDBSumWWW.read().splitlines()
>   MemoryError

However when running in on a Macbook Air it doesnt happen.

how do I get over this?

Comment: The size of the data in the linked resource is 56056571 bytes (~56 MB), the `MemoryError` most likely indicates that the machine running Windows does not have enough memory to process the available data (whereas the Macbook Air do).

Comment: Sure. How I over come this issues because the windows laptop go better specs than the Mac book Air

Comment: "Better specs" in general does not mean that your program gets more memory.  Dig through your system specs to see how much RAM a process gets by default.  Reconfigure it if you can.  Check the same on the MacBook, just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the most simple solution that I can think of to solve your problem.

In this solution the for loop will iterate over every line in the database.
every line will be assigned to the `line` variable.

```
PDBSumWWW = urllib.urlopen("https://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/pdbsum/data/seqdata.dat")
for line in PDBSumWWW:
    # Do necessary calculations. 
PDBSumWWW.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It help a lot to speed up the process!